# VBA Code filtering a column then filling down a formula for visible cells in another column

Tags: excel, vba, visible, cells

I'm quite new to macros but I'm trying to filter column AW then type in text that corresponds to that criteria in column AZ. Of course I'd like to fill down that text to the visible cells then repeat the process using other criteria filtered in column AZ. I'm using the below coding but it doesn't fill down column AZ, only in AZ2! I don't want the headers affected. Appreciate any help here!  -Amy

```
Sub Macro16()

' Macro16 Macro

'Insert Column - OK
Columns("AZ:AZ").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("AZ1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Finalized Comment"
Rows("1:1").Select
Range("AS1").Activate
Selection.AutoFilter


'Filter Combined Comment for #NA then type "Style linked to a Dropped T/P"


 Dim lastRow As Long

 With ActiveSheet
    .Range("AW2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="#N/A"
    lastRow = .Range("AW" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Range("AZ2"), .Range("AZ" & lastRow)). _
           SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = _
                     "Style Linked to a Dropped T/P"
 End With

'Filter Combined Comment for "Confirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code" then =Combined Comment

 Dim lastRow As Long

 With ActiveSheet
    .Range("AW2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Confirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code"
    lastRow = .Range("AW" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Range("AZ2"), .Range("AZ" & lastRow)). _
           SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = _
                     "Confirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code"
 End With


'Filter Combined Comment for "Unconfirmed Cost and HTS Code Present" then =Unconfirmed Cost

 Dim lastRow As Long

 With ActiveSheet
    .Range("AW2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Unconfirmed Cost and HTS Code Present"
    lastRow = .Range("AW" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Range("AZ2"), .Range("AZ" & lastRow)). _
           SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = _
                     "Unconfirmed Cost"
 End With

 'Filter Combined Comment for "Unconfirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code" then =Missing HTS

 Dim lastRow As Long

 With ActiveSheet
    .Range("AW2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Unconfirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code"
    lastRow = .Range("AW" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(.Range("AZ2"), .Range("AZ" & lastRow)). _
           SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = _
                     "Missing HTS Code"
 End With




 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Tester()
Dim lastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("AW2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Test"
        lastRow = .Range("AW" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Range("AZ2"), .Range("AZ" & lastRow)). _
               SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = _
                         "Style Linked to a Dropped T/P"
    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** updated and reworked a bit...

```
Sub Macro16()

Dim lastRow As Long

    'Insert Column - OK
    ActiveSheet.Columns("AZ:AZ").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
                       CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("AZ1").Value = "Finalized Comment"

    TagRows "#N/A", "Style Linked to a Dropped T/P"
    TagRows "Confirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code", _
            "Confirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code"
    TagRows "Unconfirmed Cost and HTS Code Present", "Unconfirmed Cost"
    TagRows "Unconfirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code", "Missing HTS Code"

End Sub

Sub TagRows(TextToFind As String, TagWithText As String)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        'filter the column for "TextToFind"
        .Range("AW:AW").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=TextToFind
        'find the last row
        lastRow = .Range("AW" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        'if any visible rows, fill in the new comment "TagWithText"
        If lastRow > 2 Then
            .Range(.Range("AZ2"), .Range("AZ" & lastRow)). _
               SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = TagWithText
        End If
        .Range("AW:AW").AutoFilter Field:=1 'clear the filter
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a dream.  :-)

Comment: Tim - When I try to use this code again for the other 3 criteria in column AZ, I get a "Duplicat Declaration in Current Scope" error (lastRow As Long) highlighted.

Comment: I'm guessing you have duplicated the line `Dim lastRow As Long` - you only need that once.

Comment: I've updated it and yes, I've duplicated the Dim lastRow As Long for each filter of column AW. Sorry, I didn't know I only needed it once.  Would you mind modifying my code so I know the placement?  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. I'm so relieved this is finally fixed!!

Answer (score 0):

Deconstructing the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) and processing strictly within in-memory arrays should speed this process up.

```
Option Explicit

Sub tagAZ()
    Dim t As Variant, vFNDs As Variant, vTAGs As Variant
    Dim a As Long, vAWs As Variant, vAZs As Variant

    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    vFNDs = Array("#N/A", "Confirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code", _
                  "Unconfirmed Cost and HTS Code Present", _
                  "Unconfirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code")
    vTAGs = Array("Style Linked to a Dropped T/P", "Confirmed Cost and Missing HTS Code", _
                  "Unconfirmed Cost", "Missing HTS Code")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns(52).Insert
        .Cells(1, 52) = "tag comment"
        .Columns(52).ColumnWidth = 32
        With .Range(.Cells(2, 49), .Cells(Rows.Count, 49).End(xlUp))
            vAWs = .Cells.Value2
            ReDim vAZs(LBound(vAWs, 1) To UBound(vAWs, 1), 1 To 1)

            For a = LBound(vAWs, 1) To UBound(vAWs, 1)
                Select Case True
                    'catch True errors
                    Case IsError(vAWs(a, 1))
                        If vAWs(a, 1) = CVErr(xlErrNA) Then _
                            vAZs(a, 1) = vTAGs(0)
                    'catch text-that-looks-like-an-error
                    Case vAWs(a, 1) = vFNDs(0)
                        vAZs(a, 1) = vTAGs(0)
                    'catch the rest
                    Case vAWs(a, 1) = vFNDs(1)
                        vAZs(a, 1) = vTAGs(1)
                    Case vAWs(a, 1) = vFNDs(2)
                        vAZs(a, 1) = vTAGs(2)
                    Case vAWs(a, 1) = vFNDs(3)
                        vAZs(a, 1) = vTAGs(3)
                End Select
            Next a

        End With

        'return processed tag comments to the worksheet
        .Cells(2, 52).Resize(UBound(vAZs, 1), UBound(vAZs, 2)) = vAZs
    End With

    appTGGL

End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Debug.Print Timer
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
    End With
End Sub
```

> <sup>Elapsed time for 250K rows of random data where 75% of the values in column AW would find a match: 2.06 seconds.</sup>
>   <sub>Running the same data through a looped [.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) equivalent (with the same environment properties disabled) took 24.25 seconds.</sub>